# Dynamic Vertical Line

Tags: css

I want to create a dynamic vertical line on the right side of my page.
I would prefer to only do this in CSS.
I want to be able to set the line at a certain height, but when the text expands the line should of course expand, also the position, vertically, should be able to be set.
So:

```
|   
| This is some text, |  
|  more text         |  
| and more text      |
|                    |
|

|
|
| This is a longer   |
| text piece.        |
| hopefully I am not |
| too confusing.     |
| And the great      |
| people here        |
| will understand    |
|                    |
|
```

Before it even comes up, no tables please.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the text into a `div` and give it a `border-right`. It will expand with the text.

**Edit per your comments:**

You could put the text into a `div` with `style="position: relative"`. You could then put another `div` into the div with:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 300px;
width: 1px;
background-color: green;
```

this should give you a green line, 300px tall, to the right hand side of your DIV. I don't have the time to test this right now but it should work consistently across browsers as long as the surrounding DIV has a width or height set.

However, this will work only with Pixel heights. Relative heights will fail, I think, because IE will interpret them as relative to *the document's* height.

Comment: Don't think I made myself clear.
I want to be able to select the height of the right line. So that it can either be shorter than the text or longer.

Comment: What do you mean by select? With the mouse, or programmatically?

Comment: With my stylesheet. I want to be able to have a line of a certain length that can be placed anywhere up or down the right hand side.

Comment: @Botto, out of curiosity, what's your use-case for this?

Comment: @Pekka, it's just to give some arbitrary styling on a site, instead of having a border that goes from the top to the bottom, I wanted a border that could be set to certain dimensions and positions.

Comment: The last question was asked by @ricebowl, I'm mentioning him so he gets notified. @Botto my approach should work for that. You can even try removing the `height` and adding `bottom: 10%` to the example above, it may give you a 90% tall line. The same works for the other directions as well of course, by replacing top, right, left....